# More Concise Pattern Matching on ADT with Multiple Data Types?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following Algebraic Data Type:

```
data Foo = Bar Int | Baz Int | Bippy
```

I'm writing a function that, given a `Foo`, returns True for anything but `Bippy`.

Is there a more concise way to implement this function than pattern matching on all data types?

```
f :: Foo -> Bool
f (Bar _) = True
f (Baz _) = True
f Bippy = False
```

In this example, it only took 3 lines of code. But, what if I had 10 data types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
f :: Foo -> Bool
f Bippy = False
f _ = True
```

And you don't have 3 data types, you've got 3 *constructors* for 1 data type.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! I know that it was not mentioned in the question, but would it be possible to match on either `Bar` or `Baz` to extract the `Int` with only 1 pattern?

Comment: You could use record syntax: `data Foo = Bar { getInt :: Int } | Baz { getInt :: Int } | Bippy` and then `p :: Foo -> Maybe Int; p Bippy = Nothing; p b = Just (getInt b)`. You could reuse it latter with [`ViewPatterns`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns): `f (p -> Just _) = True; f _ = False`.